# Format Date and Time

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In column A I have date and time.
In Column B I have this formula to split them:

```
={"COL B","COL C"; ArrayFormula(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)), SPLIT(A2:A, " ")))}
```

My sheet is linked to a Google form.
Every time a new sheet is submitted, the new data looks like **44075** and  **0.9756944444** and I always need to format as Date and the other one as time.

**Is there any way that my formula will automatically format the splitted value in col b and c?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
={"Date","Time"; ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),, {DATEVALUE(A2:A),TIMEVALUE(A2:A)}))}
```

or this:

```
 ={"Date","Time"; ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),, {INT(A2:A),MOD(A2:A,1)}))}
```

In either case, you'll want to do Format>Number Date for B and Format>Number>Time for C.

UPDATE:
Since you seem to want the formatting to appear a certain way without using the Format>Number option, this will output dates and times...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date","Time";IF(A2:A="",,TEXT(A2:A,{"m/d/yy","h:mm am/pm"}))})
```

Comment: Hi @MattKing this didn't work. I also tried  {TO_DATE(INT(A2:A).... --> didn't work either. Yes, that's what I'm currently doing - to manually format as date and the other column as time but I wanted to know if there's a formula to do that automatically.

Comment: @KBJohn I've edited my answer to include a formula that will do the formatting automatically.  But they will be TEXT values, not number values for any downstream things you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of formula and surrendered.
I've just added a script:

var date = ss.getRange('R2:R');
date.setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

```
var Time = ss.getRange('S2:S');
Time.setNumberFormat("hh:mm:ss AM/PM");
```